# How do I fix object has no attribute error in openerp?

Tags: odoo

I am getting the following error message:

> userx = self.env.user.login AttributeError: 'my.module' object has no
>   attribute 'env'

This is my code:

```
def domain_users(self):
userx = self.env.user.login
if userx == "name":
return [('exp_P','>',0)]
else:
return []
o2m_xxx = fields.One2many('my.module','rapJor_ids',string='XXX',domain = lambda self:self.domain_users())
```

Answer (score 0):

apply domain on Many2one field. You have One2many field so env not find as attribute.....